# Count occurences in column

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

In one column I have a list of comma (and whitespace) separated responses to a question such as "what music genre do you listen to?"

```
Alternative, EDM, Electronic, Hip Hop, 
Drum & Bass (D&B), Indie, House, R&B, Rap, Rock
Indie, House, R&B, Rap, Rock,
Rap, Rock
```

I want a function that will count the number of times `Rock` appears in this column

So something like

```
COUNTIFS(REGEXMATCH({A:A},"ROCK") = "TRUE")
```

but this doesn't quite work.
I'd rather not split the column out.

EDIT: Is there an easy way to also pick out the unique values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
=COUNTIF(A1:A100,"\*Rock\*")
```

[image]

Comment: one follow up question - know how to find the unique in column A here?

Comment: @ChristopherTurnbull *"how to find the unique in column A"*. Since this requires a completely different formula, please ask a new question.